# Computing probability from the Poisson distribution

Tags: r, poisson-distribution

I have a question regarding the `ppois` function in R:

- `ppois(x,lambda,lower.tail=TRUE)` gives $P[X>x]$
- `ppois(x,lambda,lower.tail=FALSE)` gives $P[X\le x]$

How can I calculate $P[X=n]$? I mean is there any function in R for this?

Comment: 'dpois' makes to job: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html

Comment: I think you have `lower.tail` the wrong way round. `ppois(q, lambda, lower.tail = TRUE)` gives $\Pr(X \le x)$

Answer (score 6):

As ocram says, `dpois(x, lambda)` gives $\Pr(X=x)$.

You can get the same result with `ppois(x,lambda)-ppois(x-1,lambda)` if $x$ is an integer.